# Oracle 12c Terminal base install

Tags: oracle

Is there other way to install ORACLE instead of GUI? Such as Terminal..
If I can't use GUI interface, then how can I install ORACLE?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a [response file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ladbi/running-oracle-universal-installer-using-a-response-file.html#GUID-C8B6ED11-4486-45E0-8365-E1A9695FB27C)

Comment: As suggested, you can use a response file. It's documented in the Installation Guide.  An entire section named "Installing and Configuring Oracle Database Using Response Files"  But I'm curious as to why you can't use the GUI interface?

Comment: Umm.. I want to prepare the case that I can't use GUI. Could you let me know the reason why you are curious? It's bad? or difficult to use? But, reaaaally thank you so much. Really.

Comment: If we're talking Unix/Linux here you could also forward X to another (X) server. So you don't need to have the X server installed on the target machine (but some X client stuff) but could use the GUI.